# How to get a manipulated plot of the intersection points of two curves without finding them numerically?

Tags: plotting, assumptions, intersection

I have four 2-variables functions for $0<x<3$ and $1<y<3$

```
f := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[  3 x])/(2 x);
g := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/  x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] - Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];
h := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/  x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] + Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];
k := Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x;
```

I want to show the intersection points of the curves $\{f,g\}$ and $\{f,h\}$ in the  `PlotRange-> {-1,1}` assuming that $\{f,g,h,k\}\neq\pm1$ and without using numerical methods like `Solve` and `NSolve` (since I have to do the same for other functions over a larger domain of x, so, it is impossible to do them all numerically).

**My questions:**

> 1. For example for $y=2$, using `y := 2; Plot[ {f, g, h}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]` , I need a picture like the attached picture (showing the intersection points with different colors in a same line above the plot). Moreover, and if possible, I want to have a manipulated form of this picture as $y$ changes from $1$ to $3$. But even this simple code for manipulation does not work

```
Manipulate[  Plot[ {f, g, h}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]  ,  {y, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: "without using numerical methods like Solve and NSolve" - why? Is this homework?

Comment: @MarcoB Absolutely not. I have to do this for a huge number of cases over a larger domain of $x$, so, it is impossible to do them all numerically! Moreover, I tried NSolve but it gives extra roots that I have to check with the plots and exclude them manually which is very time-consuming and probably with a high chance of making mistakes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ClearAll[lines, pies]

funcs = {f, g, h};

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@funcs];

funcpairs = Subsets[funcs, {2}];

colorpairs = Subsets[colors, {2}];

legend = LineLegend[colors, funcs, LegendLayout -> "Row"];

lines[y_, xrange_: {0, 3}, vrange_: {1, -1}] := 
  MapThread[Plot[Evaluate[Through@#[x, y]], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
     PlotStyle -> #2, PlotRange -> vrange] &, {funcpairs, colorpairs}];


pies[col_, ints_, vpos_: 1.1, r_ : .03] := Graphics[Flatten @ (Thread[#, List, {2}]&/@ 
     DeleteCases[{_, {}}] @ Thread[{col, ints}] /. {c : {__}, x_Real} :> 
      Thread[{c, Disk[{x, vpos}, r, Pi {1/2, 3/2} + #] & /@ {0, Pi}}])]

Manipulate[Module[{plots = lines[y], intersections}, 
  intersections = Map[Map[First], Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections /@ plots];
  Legended[
   Show[plots, pies[colorpairs, intersections], 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    GridLines -> {Flatten @ intersections, None}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 30}}], 
   Placed[legend, Above]]], {y, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

To use  points instead of `pies`, define `points` as

```
ClearAll[points]
points[col_, ints_, vpos_: 1.1, ps_: AbsolutePointSize[10]] := 
 Graphics[Thread[{col, ps, Point /@ Map[Thread[{#, vpos}] &]@ints}]]
```

and replace `pies[colorpairs, intersections]` with `points[{Orange, Green, Magenta}, intersections]` to get

[image]

To use a different domain for `x` (say, `{x, 0, 10}`), use `lines[y, {0, 10}]` instead of `lines[y]`.

Replace `lines[y]` with `lines[y, {0, 5}, {-2, 2}]` and `points[{Orange, Green, Magenta}, intersections]` with `points[{Orange, Green, Magenta}, intersections, 2.2]` to get

[image]

**Note:** I defined `f`, `g` and `h` as

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
f[x_, y_] := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[3 x])/(2 x)

g[x_, y_] := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2]

h[x_, y_] := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] + 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly what I meant. However, when I increase the domain of $x$, the code does not work. I guess some part of it should be changed if I change the domain of $x$. I am a beginner in Mathematica and I want to use this code for different functions and over a large domain of $x$; may you kindly explain which parts of the code I should modify when I change the functions and the domain of $x$ and $y$.  And how can I have those points only in orange and green (as in the plot attached to the text) ?   @kglr

Comment: For example for $0<x<10$.

Comment: @math2021, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks again. But why we should use $[-2,2]$? in this way, one intersection point (the orange point close to $3$ is redundant). I need only intersections in the range $[-1,1]$.  @kglr

Comment: @math2021, added that argument _just in case_ you want to use a vertical range different from `{-1,1}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. @kglr

Answer (score 9):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f := Cos[
    3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[
       3 x])/(2 x);
g := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
    x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[
         3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/
         x)^2];
h := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
    x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] + 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[
         3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/
         x)^2];
k := Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x;
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[Module[{
   colorsDot = {Green, Red, Blue},
   colorsLine = ColorData[97] /@ Range[3],
   pairs = Subsets[{"f", "g", "h"}, {2}]},
  Legended[
   Legended[
    Show[
     Show[
        plt = 
         Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[#[[1]]] /. y -> yv], {x, 0, 3},
          PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
          PlotStyle -> #[[2]]],
        Graphics[{PointSize[Large], #[[3]], 
          Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt]}]] & /@
      
      Transpose[
       {pairs, Subsets[colorsLine, {2}], colorsDot}]],
    Placed[PointLegend[colorsDot, And @@@ pairs,
      LegendLayout -> "Row"],
     Top]],
   Placed[LineLegend[colorsLine, {"f", "g", "h"},
     LegendLayout -> "Row"],
    Bottom]]],
 {{yv, 1, y}, 1, 3, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To add dots at top of chart over the intersections and variable range for x:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{
   colorsDot = {Green, Red, Blue},
   colorsLine = ColorData[97] /@ Range[3],
   pairs = Subsets[{"f", "g", "h"}, {2}],
   plt, pts},
  Legended[
   Legended[
    Show[
     Show[
        plt = Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[#[[1]]] /. y -> yv], {x, 0, xmax},
          PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
          PlotStyle -> #[[2]]],
        Graphics[{PointSize[Large], #[[3]],
          pts = Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt],
          pts /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 1.1}}],
        PlotRangeClipping -> False,
        ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 20}}] & /@
      Transpose[{pairs, Subsets[colorsLine, {2}], colorsDot}]],
    Placed[
     PointLegend[colorsDot, And @@@ pairs,
      LegendLayout -> "Row"],
     Top]],
   Placed[
    LineLegend[colorsLine, {"f", "g", "h"},
     LegendLayout -> "Row"],
    Bottom]]],
 {{xmax, 3, Subscript[x, max]}, 2, 10, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{yv, 1, y}, 1, 3, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Is it possible to have those points manipulated as in kglr's answer in your code? @Bob Hanlon

Comment: @math2021 - The dots in the plot are at the intersections and move when you move the slider (i.e., move when the intersections move). The dots at the top are just a legend that indicates what the color of the dots represents. This is analogous to the legend at the bottom which tells you which color line corresponds to which function.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. Yes, I understood these you mentioned. But I need a manipulated form of the points on a line apart from the curves (as the one kglr suggested). I wanted to know if it is possible to do that with your code as well. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: See edit for added points and variable range for x

Comment: Thank you again. Both answers are exactly the ones I was looking for. Unfortunately, I can choose only one of them as the accepted answer. I really appreciate your time, guidance, and for sharing your expertise.  @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Is it possible to use a different plot marker, say, "+" instead of points? @ Bob Hanlon

Comment: @math2021 - What have you tried? The answer by kglr showed an example using graphics. If after looking at his answer and the documentation you run in to problems, post a question showing what you have tried and the problems you have encountered. Do not ask questions in comments.

Comment: I know that it is possible to change PlotMarker in graphics, but since your code uses Mesh functions, I was not sure if it is possible to change the marker. Thank you anyway for the tip. @Bob Hanlon